# tslint-teamcity-reporter не работает через npm run

Tags: веб-программирование, code-style, непрерывная-интеграция, teamcity, tslint

Пытаюсь подключить [tslint-teamcity-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-teamcity-reporter) для запуска через `npm run`.

При непосредственном запуске из консоли

```
Z:\>tslint --formatters-dir node_modules/tslint-teamcity-reporter/ --format TSHintTeamcity "src/**/*.ts"
```

всё работает верно:

```
##teamcity[testSuiteStarted name='TSLint: src/app/app.resolver.ts']
##teamcity[testStarted name='(13,46) Missing semicolon']
##teamcity[testFailed name='(13,46) Missing semicolon' message='|[semicolon|] Missing semicolon' detailed='']
##teamcity[testFinished name='(13,46) Missing semicolon']
##teamcity[testSuiteFinished name='TSLint: src/app/app.resolver.ts']
```

Но при попытке запустить через `npm run`

```
Z:\>npm run tslint --formatters-dir node_modules/tslint-teamcity-reporter/ --format TSHintTeamcity "src/**/*.ts"
```

что-то идёт не так:

```
> some-app@0.0.2 tslint Z:\
> tslint "node_modules/tslint-teamcity-reporter/" "TSHintTeamcity" "src/**/*.ts"

fs.js:725
  var r = binding.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position);
                  ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:725:19)
    at processFile (Z:\node_modules\tslint\lib\tslint-cli.js:121:12)
    at Z:\node_modules\tslint\lib\tslint-cli.js:177:74
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Z:\node_modules\tslint\lib\tslint-cli.js:177:41)

    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "tslint" "--formatters-dir" "node_modules/tslint-teamcity-reporter/" "--format" "TSHintTeamcity" "src/**/*.ts"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! some-app@0.0.2 tslint: `tslint "node_modules/tslint-teamcity-reporter/" "TSHintTeamcity" "src/**/*.ts"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the some-app@0.0.2 tslint script 'tslint "node_modules/tslint-teamcity-reporter/" "TSHintTeamcity" "src/**/*.ts"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the some-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tslint "node_modules/tslint-teamcity-reporter/" "TSHintTeamcity" "src/**/*.ts"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs some-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls some-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     Z:\npm-debug.log
```

Секция `scripts` в файле `package.json` содержит следующие команды:

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
  "lint:teamcity": "npm run tslint --formatters-dir node_modules/tslint-teamcity-reporter/ --format TSHintTeamcity \"src/**/*.ts\"",
  "tslint": "tslint",
  ...
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть внимательнее, то `npm run` вызывает

```
> tslint "node_modules/tslint-teamcity-reporter/" "TSHintTeamcity" "src/**/*.ts"
```

т. е. `--formatters-dir` и `--format` потерялись.

Для правильной передачи надо использовать `--`:

```
npm run tslint -- --formatters-dir node_modules/tslint-teamcity-reporter/ --format TSHintTeamcity -- "src/**/*.ts"
```

а скрипты переписать следующим образом:

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
  "lint:teamcity": "npm run tslint -- --formatters-dir node_modules/tslint-teamcity-reporter/ --format TSHintTeamcity \"src/**/*.ts\"",
  "tslint": "tslint",
  ...
},
```